# How can i add a MouseDown event handler to a <asp: button> control?

Tags: events

I have a aspx page that contain "asp:RequiredFieldValidator" controls;Problem that is when each of "asp:RequiredFieldValidator" controls activate and show their messages; other controls in my page don't working even "CANCEL" button!!!
i want to enable  controls in my "NEXT" button MouseDown  and then disable them at my "NEXT" button MouseUp.
Thanks for any other solutions...

Answer (score 1):

Specifically to answer your question as stated in your title: to add additional event handlers to an asp:button or other server controls that are not composite you simply add the handler to the element. Include onmousedown="myMouseDownHandler(this);" in the element and the javascript function myMouseDownHandler will fire.

However, I **think** there is a better way to do what your asking but the description of the question is not coherent enough for me to quite figure out what you're asking. I realize you may not be a native English speaker but perhaps you could give it another pass.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ValidationGroup** property on controls that are validated and controls that triggers validation (e.g. save/update buttons) and on validators. 
 Additionally set **CausesValidation** property to false on each button that does not need to trigger validation (cancel button).